# How to release a service acquired via IServiceProvider?

Tags: .net-core

How do you release a service that was instantiated at runtime via IServiceProvider (.net core 2.0)?

I don't see any kind of .Release(obj) method on IServiceProvider.

Comment: "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous.  The COM interface by that name has a Release() method.  A .NET interface (dependency injection perhaps) does not, the GC gets the job done.

Answer (score 4):

With the supported lifetimes there's no need for a Release method.

- Transient dependency will be GC'ed when out of scope.
- Singleton
  will be instantiated when first resolved and its reference held by
  the container until it's disposed (often only when the app shuts down)
- Scoped will be held by the scope which is created
  to serve a web request or whatever mechanism that relies on scopes.